# testAction() function returns null on debug() in CakePhp testing

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit

I was trying to learn how to use unit testing in CakePhp, I'm trying to write a controller test. I read about testAction() and debug() function, but It doesn't work for me, I mean, the test method passes, but the debug() returns null (because testAction does)

This is my code:

```
<?php
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
App::uses('View', 'View');
App::uses('PostsController', 'Controller');

class PostsControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase {
    public function setUp() {
       parent::setUp();
       $Controller = new Controller();
       $View = new View($Controller);
       $this->Posts = new PostsController($View);
    }

    public function testIndex() {
          $result = $this->testAction('Posts/Index');
        debug($result);        

    }
}
```

Posts/index controller returns a list of all posts stored in the DB.

Comment: Try `$this->testAction('posts/index');`

Answer (score 10):

I'm assuming you're using CakePHP 2.

`$this->testAction()` can return a few different results, depending on the options you give it.

For example, if you set the `return` option to `vars`, the `testAction()` method will return an array of the vars that have been set in the tested action:

```
public function testIndex() {
    $result = $this->testAction('/posts/index', array('return' => 'vars'));
    debug($result);
}
```

In this example, the debug data should be an array of the vars that you set in the `/posts/index` action.

The CakePHP documentation describes the possible results that you can have returned here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#choosing-the-return-type

Note that the default option, `result`, gives you the value that your controller action **returns**. For most controller actions this will be `null`, so the fact that you're getting `null` in your example is to be expected.

Answer (score 1):

mtnorthrop's answer did work for me, but only once I also dealt with my site's authorization as well.
If your site uses authorization, then testAction('/action', array('return' => 'contents') will return null. I've seen a few solutions for this:

One is to follow the solution given here:
[CakePHP Unit Test Not Returning Content or View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504572/cakephp-unit-test-not-returning-content-or-view)
where you check in AppController::beforeFilter() whether you are in debug mode, and if so, always authenticate the user:

```
// For Mock Objects and Debug >= 2 allow all (this is for PHPUnit Tests)
if(preg_match('/Mock_/',get_class($this)) && Configure::read('debug') >= 2){
    $this->Auth->allow();
}
```

Another is to follow the suggestions given in this discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cake-php/eWCO2bf5t98
and to mock the Auth object using the ControllerTestCase's generate function:

```
class MyControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase {
    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->controller = $this->generate('My',
            array('components' => array(
                'Auth' => array('isAuthorized')
            ))
        );
        $this->controller->Auth->expects($this->any())
            ->method('isAuthorized')
            ->will($this->returnValue(true));

    }
}
```

Note (I'm using CakePhp 2.3.8)

Comment: It is never a good idea to add "am I in a test" checks to production code - mocking classes is a good/the right way to address that. You should have asked and answered a new question - while related this answer is not for _this_ question.

Comment: I agree with @AD7six in theory. But practice inevitably seems to be different than theory. Thanks to @efeder for pointing me in the right direction. I am using [CakePHP's Security component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html) and `requireSecure`. I don't see any documentation on using `testAction` with https, and thus not using `requireSecure`  in debug mode seems like a good solution.

Comment: @tyler you should imo consider asking a question about that as it's not directly related to this question/answer and pretty trivial to mock any component functions with test action.