# CakePHP Unit Testing with edit methods

Tags: cakephp, phpunit

I wrote the test `testEdit()`.

```
public function testEdit() {
    $result = $this->_testAction('/articles/edit/1', array('return' => 'vars', 'method' => 'get'));
    debug($result);

}
```

why `debug($result)` show the null array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [testAction() function returns null on debug() in CakePhp testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431127/testaction-function-returns-null-on-debug-in-cakephp-testing)

Answer (score 1):

Use `var_dump` instead of `debug`

```
public function testEdit() {
    $result = $this->testAction('/articles/edit/1', array('return' => 'vars', 'method' => 'get'));
    var_dump($result);
}
```

Comment: It dumps `array(0) { }`

Comment: :D So it no more null. (Y) Show what is `_testAction` is ur code

Comment: Yes, it should display like this `'Article' => array(
                'title' => 'Fourth Title',
                'content' => 'Fourth Title Body',
                'published' => '1',
                'created' => '2015-05-18 10:40:34',
                'updated' => '2015-05019 10:23:34'
            )`

Comment: This is the `_testAction` `$this->_testAction('/articles/edit/1', array('return' => 'vars', 'method' => 'get'));`

Comment: What is the version of CakePHP you are running

Comment: I am using `CakePHP-2.6`

Comment: Can u remove `_` infront of the testAction.

Comment: `_testAction` and `testAction` both display the `null array`.

Comment: Hope this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431127/testaction-function-returns-null-on-debug-in-cakephp-testing) will help